# UIScrollView memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, core-plot

I have 5 custom views which inherit from `CPTGraphHostingView`, i.e they are 5 different plots build using Core Plot Framework.
I initialize these plots and add as subviews to an `UIScrollView`. Each view is fullscreen, and I'm using pagination to scroll to different plot. The problem is that when I'm loading all this stuff, memory increases significantly, and there is a risk of app crash. How can I optimize the memory usage?

Comment: If scrolling vertically, use a `UITableView`, if scrolling horizontally, use a `UICollectionView`. Both will let you manage the plot views (i.e., create and hold on to them only for as long as they are visible).

Comment: Also check the wwdc videos from last year where they show a photo gallery using uiscrollview. that was doing the same thing - all the photos didn't fit in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you are loading all the CPTGraphHostingView at once because of that memory is getting increased significantly. As per description you are using horizontal pagination to load next view.
You can use following option to optimise memory usage

1. As you are putting  CPTGraphHostingView on scroll view user is able to view only one graph at time. so you need to add only the view which user is currently using. When user goes to next page remove previous view from superview and make it nil. And create new CPTGraphHostingView with required data and add it to subview. This approach will keep only current view in memory.
2. You use horizontal UICollectionView which will only keep views in memory as long as they are visible.